# Failed to parse file highlighted_text_material.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I run the app and got this problem every time I do. I've been trying to fix this cus at first, it says failed cus of other failures and I've changed Android Version to

> API 21:Android API 21

render and got this error.

```
Failed to parse file
C:..\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\data\res\color\highlighted_text_material.xml
```

highlighted_text_material.xml is shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2015 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="0.4"
          android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
</selector>
```

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: I've edited with the xml file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the path `C:..\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\data\res\color\highlighted_text_material.xml`, it is using android-23, so you probably need to change the api to 23 and try to compile.

Comment: Right, Got it... Thanks mate. I've fixed some others but just got confused with this silly error... Thanks for the help